# How to make image banner and two div cards responsive for every sreensize

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an image banner with some text and buttons on top of it and two widgets right next to it in a flex (watch image for reference). I want them to be responsive when the screen changes sizes.

```
<div className="tabs">
          <div className="tabs-container">
            <img src={MainBG} alt="background" className="banner-img" />
            <div className="top-text">
              <div>
                <h1>
                  Track Crypto Activity <br /> For Smarter Trading
                </h1>
                <button className="join-button"> Join Now</button>
                <button className="academy-button"> Crypto Academy</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="widgets">
            <TechnicalAnalysis
              colorTheme="dark"
              width="280"
              height="305"
              symbol="BITSTAMP:BTCUSD"
            />
            <TechnicalAnalysis
              colorTheme="dark"
              width="280"
              height="305"
              symbol="BINANCE:ETHUSDT"
            />
          </div>
```

[How the Ui is on one screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSbGw.png)

Here is the current CSS:

```
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
.banner-img {
  width: 95%;
}
.tabs-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.top-text {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: white;
  top: 50px;
}

.join-button {
  background-color: #bb46e2;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
}

.academy-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.academy-button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #bb46e2;
}

.widgets {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

How do I make these responsive for all screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries. You can use those it change the styling of elements depending on the screen size. Read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).

Comment: Yes, I am using those. I was wondering if there was a different way

Comment: @HusnainMehmood I don't see them in the code you provided. And to my knowledge, you can't do it another way with only CSS. You can probably do it with JS thought.

Comment: Yes, did not include it. How can we do it through JS?

Comment: @HusnainMehmood I personly don't know how to. I'm sure somebody else does thought.